# How to call success callback function of knockout model from AjaxForm in mvc

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, mvvm, knockout.js

I'm a newbie in web. Now I'm learning mvc and i have a question. A have a knockout model and a Ajax.BeginForm. I can call "Todo" function as callback without error but it can't work when I try to use "success" function in model like (new AjaxOptions() { HttpMethod = "Post", OnSuccess = "LoginViewModel.success")

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("Todo", "Account", new AjaxOptions() { HttpMethod = "Post", OnSuccess = "Todo" }))
{
    <input type="text" name="UserName" data-bind="value: name"/>
    <br />
    <input type="password" name="Password" data-bind="value: password"/>
    <input type="submit"/>
}

<script type="text/javascript">

    function LoginViewModel() {
        var self = this;

        self.name = ko.observable("Hello");
        self.password= ko.observable("1234");

        self.success = function () {
            alert("Hello!");
        };
    }

    ko.applyBindings(new LoginViewModel());

    function Todo(data, status, xhr) {
        alert("asd");
    }

</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should do the following:

```
var viewModel = new LoginViewModel();
ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
```

Then you can use:

```
(new AjaxOptions() { HttpMethod = "Post", OnSuccess = "viewModel.success")
```

You can see here that you need to create an object of the view model and then call the success method of the object.

I'd also recommend to just use jquery for the ajax calls instead of using the ajax in mvc.